# How to check when app has 'come to rest' when waiting on a long series of data processing and network related callbacks

Tags: ios, objective-c, networking, healthkit

I'm doing a large-scale data read from the Apple Health respository. I am reading several kinds of data. For each kind of data I am requesting all data from all sources for all time by doing a source query to get all the sources per data type and then doing a data query for all time per source for data type.

When the data is retrieved, I aggregate it algorithmically and upload the results of the aggregation to a remote server to sync the user's account data across devices.

The result of this structure is

Per source 
(1) A query with a callback that returns the list of sources
(2) For each source, another query that returns the data for each source, in a callback
(3) In that last callback, data is then processed and made ready for upload. When the upload is completed, there is a final callback

I can't know the timing or number of queries. I have also noted that sometimes HealthKit callbacks are not returned ( I think it's something to do with the underlying SQLite db stopping responding/timing out connections?).

So how can I know or guess when the process is over? I'd like to find a way to know the app has 'come to rest' by which I mean there are no disk read/writes and no network activity going on anymore. What's a good way to do this that, say, could check app activity in the last 30 seconds and if there has been no network or read/write activity, declares the process 'finished' and makes the UI available again?

Answer (score 0):

Create a singleton class that tracks the number of outstanding queries.  When a new request starts, tell it to increment a counter (either with an atomic increment or by performing the work using dispatch_sync onto the main thread if it isn't already running there).  When each request ends, tell that singleton class to decrement the counter.

If there are dependent resource requests (e.g. if requesting resource A tells the app that it also needs to fetch resource B and resource C), be sure that you start those subsequent requests (or at least enqueue them to start) in a way that increments the counter in the singleton class **before** you decrement the counter on the original resource.

In that singleton class, block the UI (if that's really necessary) with a loading screen whenever the value goes from zero to nonzero, and unblock it (hiding the loading screen) when it goes to zero again.